# How do you politely and gratefully reply to an invitation to be published?

Tags: nuances, politeness, keigo, email, academic-japanese

Is there a set phrase for politely replying to an invitation to have your academic paper published as a journal article?

I presented a paper at a Japanese academic conference, and I've received an email from the academic society's committee which says they have selected it to have it published in their annual academic journal
(「発表者には要旨原稿をいただきたいということになりました。」) and that I must first reply to let them know whether or not I accept the invitation (「まずは要旨掲載を希望するか否か、ご意向をお知らせ下さい。」).

I want to thankfully accept the invitation. If I reply with

> ご連絡ありがとうございます。
>
> はい、要旨掲載を希望します。
>
> よろしくお願いします。

is that okay, or is it not polite enough?  Is there a set phrase that should be used?  Should the reply be longer?  Should I thank them specifically for choosing or for considering my paper for publication?

---

**Edit:**

kimbrys notes, "it might be quite too short of an answer for such email" and naruto writes, "you can't be too polite." How can I write this sort of response email longer and more robustly in order to be more polite? What additional sort of content would be standard?

This time, I received the instructions 「…掲載する論文の執筆を依頼することが決まりました。以下に執筆要領を記しますので、それに従いご執筆願えるか否か、諾否をお知らせ下さい。」

Comment: What is a politer version of 「はい」? I am only familiar with alternatives to it that can be used in certain contents only, such as 「畏まりました」or「了解です」 or 「よろしい」 or 「そうです」, but I do not think I have heard of another word that equates to a politer version of 「はい」.

Comment: If you are going to submit a totally new article, you can't be too polite. But in this case, I think your suggestion is already fair enough, although not the politest. If you feel your email is too short, a good phrase of excuse is 「（取り急ぎ、）用件のみにて失礼します」.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

お返事ありがとうございました。

掲載していただければ光栄です。

どうぞ宜しくお願いいたします。

Yet, it might be quite too short of an answer for such email.