# after saying "ありがとう" to someone, they can't renege without hard feelings?

Tags: word-choice

In the thread titled [usage cases for 「ありがたい」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17584/usage-cases-for-%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84) many very good answers were given. However, one issue that was not addressed was (when speaking formally) whether ありがたい *brings an end to the thought*. What I mean is that

- "ありがとう" might mean "thank you very much. and whatever i am thanking you for is a done deal. reneging is not acceptable."
- "ありがたい" seems more like "i fully expect you to do what i am thankful for. but, stuff happens and you can renege without any hard feelings."

So, that is why in the thread titled [how do you politely and gratefully reply to an invitation to be published](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18771/how-do-you-politely-and-gratefully-reply-to-an-invitation-to-be-published), I would say:

"ご掲載になってくださって、**ありがたい** です。これからも、よろしくお願いします"
rather than
"ご掲載になってくださって、**ありがとう** ございます。これからも、よろしくお願いします。"

The *usage cases for 「ありがたい」* thread already answers every question I have about 「ありがたい」。 But, with regard to the very specific usage case given in this thread, is that difference between **ありがたい** and **ありがとう** there?

Comment: ご掲載になってくださって ←　Do you mean... 掲載していただき or 採用していただき?

Comment: @Choko With regard to meaning, "xになってくださる" didn't make perfect sense to me. But, I liked the honorific sense of "them giving" rather than "my taking". I went with "になって" because (-) "xしてくださって" sounded weird (-) "xやってくださって" seems too informal (-) "xなさってくださって" seems too honorific. The only other options I thought I had were "xになってくださって" or "xにしてくださって". So, I guessed "xになって". The entire phrase is also just a guess.

Comment: There's also stuff like ありがたく思う which you may also be interested in.

Comment: @user312440 "なってくださる", I think, is called 二重敬語 and is not preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ありがたい is used when something is convenient/beneficial/welcome to the speaker. And it's very often used with "if/もしも-clause" or 仮定形 conjucation.

> 論文を掲載していただければ、ありがたいです。 (before your article is reviewed)
>
> 教えてくれればありがたい(です)。(before someone actually teaches you something)

And yes, sentences like these mean that your offer may or may not be accepted. (By the way, in the cover letter of a scientific article, I recommend replacing ありがたいです with 幸い【さいわい】です, which is even politer.)

I'd say 連用形 + ありがたい (present tense) is very unnatural:

> (*) 間違いを教えてくれて、ありがたい(です)。
> (*) 論文を掲載していただき、ありがたいです。

But using ありがたかった after something was already done is OK:

> 間違いを教えてくれて、ありがたかった。(≒ It was kind of X to point out ...)

On the other hand, ありがとう(ございます) is *Thank you*, and it's usually used when something was already done, or determined to be done.

> 論文を掲載していただき、ありがとうございます。(after your article was successfully published)
>
> 教えてくれてありがとう(ございます)。(after someone actually taught you something)